# How to loop a Console.ReadLine?

Tags: c#

I cannot figure out how to read user-input in a loop (with `Console.ReadLine`). I'm trying to create a note that lets me store what ever the user inputs, and exits if he types exit.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Note myNote = new Note();
            Note otherNote = new Note();
            myNote.addText("Hi there");
            Console.WriteLine(myNote.display());
            otherNote.addText(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(otherNote.display());
            if (otherNote = "exit")
            {

            }

        }
    }


}


    class Note
{
    private string text = "";
    private DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now;
    private DateTime modifiedStamp = DateTime.Now;
    int maxLength = 10;


    public void addText(string sometext)
    {
        if (text.Length + sometext.Length < maxLength)
        {
            text += sometext;
            modifiedStamp = DateTime.Now;
        }

    }

    public string display()
    {
        return "Created: " + timeStamp.ToString() + "\n" +
            "Modified: " + modifiedStamp.ToString() + "\n" +
            "Content: " + text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your code to VS before posting. It will format your code as I edited..

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to loop the writeline so that the user can input notes until it types exit? So the user can input 0 note, 1, 2 or 99 or n notes?

Comment: whats VS? sorry new to this site..

Comment: Use a while loop with a break condition.

Comment: yes, thats the idea. i was thinking of storing the user input to an array,,like every time the user types something and hit enter, it will store to an array, then again until user inputs "exit"

Comment: @edM VS = Visual Studio.

Comment: You'll need a List<Note> if you want to store every notes until the user enter "exit". Also the timestamp should be done in the constructor for Note otherwise all notes will have the same timestamp. The answers seems to believe you only want 2 notes but it seems you want N notes.

Comment: Sorry i think i pasted a different version of the code that i was trying to solve,.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need List of Notes in order to add as many notes as you want.
Additionally, you need to first save `ReadLine` input check if the user really asked to exit otherwise keep adding notes.

```
var myNotes = new List<Note>();
var firstNote = new Note();
firstNote.addText("Hi there");

Note note;
while (true)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        break;
    }
    note = new Note();
    note.addText(input);
    myNotes.Add(note);
}
```

Comment: i tried your code, it works, but the "bool kepAddingNotes = true;" is giving me warning in VS, says assigned but value was never used,.. and thanks btw.

Comment: @Orel Eraki how can i apply my method display on your code

Comment: Just add: `Console.WriteLine(note.display());` after `myNotes.Add(note);`

Answer (score 1):

The general format is to use something like this (a while loop with a break condition):

```
// put code above while loop that only needs to be executed once
while (true) {        
    // get the user input for every iteration, allowing to exit at will
    String line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line.Equals("exit")) {
        // exit the method.
        return; // use "break" if you just want to exit the loop
    }
    // this is what will happen in the loop body since we didn't exit
    // put whatever note stuff you want to execute again and again in here
}
```

You'll want to edit what goes into the body of this loop depending on what exactly you want done with your note instances. But generally, you repeatedly prompt a user for input until some condition is met and then you break out of the loop. You may decided that condition (e.g. "enter 10 notes"; "type exit"; etc.)

Comment: I think he wants to add N notes until the user enter "exit". The 2 new notes are a mistake. I could add an answer supporting a List of note but I think it would be kinda rude on my part.

Comment: `do ... while` loop would be more suitable here. And would allow sensible exit condition, not just `while(true)`

Comment: Ok thanks everyone. i think i get what you all mean,(I think..) i'm very new to C# thank you very much for your replies..
@eser the code is copied straight from visual studio

Comment: @n0rd good point with `do ... while` its better for console menus

Comment: I cant add `exit` as a text note :D

Answer (score 0):

Per @n0rd's comment, here's how a do...while loop could work:

```
string input;
var myNotes = new List<Note>();
do{
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!input.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
        var note = new Note();
        note.addText(input);
        myNotes.Add(note);
    }
} while (!input.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is this:

```
List<string> simpleList = new List<string> { "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo" }; //Dummy data source
Console.WriteLine("Enter a call sign to find in the list. Press X to exit: "); //Prompt

string callSign;
string exitKey = "x";

while ((callSign = Console.ReadLine().ToLower()) != exitKey)
{ //This is where the "Magic" happens
    if (simpleList.Contains(callSign))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\"{callSign}\" exists in our simple list");//Output should the list contain our entry
        Console.WriteLine(""); //Not really relevant, just needed to added spacing between input and output
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\"{callSign}\" does not exist in our simple list"); //Output should the list not contain our entry
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a call sign to find in the list. Press X to exit: ");//Prompt
}
```

The line:

```
while ((callSign = Console.ReadLine().ToLower()) != exitKey) {
      ...
```

is where the loop happens. If the entry does not equal the exitKey, the steps are repeated.

Answer (score 0):

**To loop Console.ReadLine() you can use this**

```
    `List<string> al = new List<string>(); //list to store string values
    while(true)
    {
        string f = Console.ReadLine();
        if(f == null)         //check if string is null or not
        {
            break;
        }
        else
            al.Add(f);        //add strings to list
    }`
```